# Implementation of M-spline in R

Tags: r, splines

I am implementing M-spline in R as defined here : http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/manual/spline.html and originally in Ramsay (1988).

In short, we define a list of knots $t$ such that  :

$0=t_1=...=t_k<t_{k+1}<...<t_{k+m}<t_{k+m+1}=...=t_{k+m+k}=1$

So the $k$ first knots are 0 and the $k$ last knots are 1 with $m$ inner knots.

The Mi spline of order k with knots t is define recursively as below :

$M_i(x|1,t) = 1 / (t_{i+1} – t_i), t_i ≤ x < t_{i+1},$ 0 otherwise

$M_i(x|k,t) = k [(x–t_i)M_i(x|k–1,t) + (t_{i+k}–x)M_{i+1}(x|k–1,t)] / ((k–1)(t_{i+k}–t_i))$

The problem is that if I want the M-splines of order 3 (k=3), the $M_1$ spline and the $M_{k+m}$ spline do not exist because when it calculate $M_i(x|k–1,t)$ it divides by $(t_{i+k}–t_i)$ but since now $k=3-1=2$ and $i=1$ (or $m+k$), $(t_{i+k}–t_i)$ is $(t_{1+2}–t_1)=0$ since the first three knots are 0 (same thing for the last one).

So the definition seems to have a problem. Here is my implementation in R with an example of the problem. Here k=3 and m=3.

```
ts = c(0,0,0,0.3,0.5,0.6,1,1,1)
Mk = function(i,k,x,ts){
  if(k==1){
    if(ts[i]<=x && x<ts[i+1]){1/(ts[i+1]-ts[i])}
    else{0}
  }
  else{
    #print(paste(i,k))
    #print((ts[i+k]-ts[i]))
    k*((x-ts[i])*Mk(i,k-1,x,ts)+(ts[i+k]-x)*Mk(i+1,k-1,x,ts))/((k-1)*(ts[i+k]-ts[i]))

  }
}
Mk(1,3,.4,ts)
```

Note that my code and the definition seems to work for all the "inner" splines.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after some tweaking with my code I tried to add this line to the definition of Mk :

```
    if(ts[i+k]-ts[i]==0){0}
```

So that when it goes out of the list, the spline is simply zero. It worked and I could confirm that the basis was right.

Comment: Nice, thanks! Note that testing exact equality of floating point numbers may give unexpected results: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Answer (score 3):

Though I know it is not a new question, just want to mention one existing implementation of M-splines in R for reference.

Package **[splines2](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=splines2)** provides function named `mSpline` for M-splines. If you had experience of using package **splines**, you have probably known how to use `mSpline` already since its user interface is exactly the same with `bs` for B-splines in package **splines**.

In addition, the M-spline bases are evaluated by taking advantage of a simple transformation between B-spline and M-spline bases, while the evaluation of B-splines is efficiently done by package **splines** and implemented in C. Therefore, the function `mSpline` should have a better performance in speed, compared with direct implementation by recursive formulas purely in R.

A quick demonstration is available in the package [vignettes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/splines2/vignettes/splines2-intro.html#mSpline).